# How to copy a file along with directory structure/path using python?

Tags: python, file, directory, copy

First thing I have to mention here, I'm new to python.

Now I have a file located in:

```
a/long/long/path/to/file.py
```

I want to copy to my home directory with a new folder created:

```
/home/myhome/new_folder
```

My expected result is:

```
/home/myhome/new_folder/a/long/long/path/to/file.py
```

Is there any existing library to do that? If no, how can I achieve that?

Comment: there you go, this already explains it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994488/copy-file-or-directory-in-python

Comment: May be http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile ?

Comment: @Anderson Green: it is not a duplicate. The accepted answers if swapped *won't work* for the questions. They are closely related (copying stuff in Python); it doesn't make them identical. Please, read the full the question and look at the answers before voting to close next time.

Comment: it's a while ago, but generally speaking a good tactic if there is a similar but not identical question, is to reference the existing question in one's own question, and state how one's own question is different.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

To create all intermediate-level destination directories you could use [`os.makedirs()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os#os.makedirs) before copying:

```
import os
import shutil

srcfile = 'a/long/long/path/to/file.py'
dstroot = '/home/myhome/new_folder'


assert not os.path.isabs(srcfile)
dstdir =  os.path.join(dstroot, os.path.dirname(srcfile))

os.makedirs(dstdir) # create all directories, raise an error if it already exists
shutil.copy(srcfile, dstdir)
```

Comment: for the last line, **dstdir** is a directory, it should be
```
    os.makedirs(dstdir)
    dstfile = os.path.join(dst, src)
    shutil.copyfile(src, dstfile)
```

Comment: @RebornJs: `copy()` supports a directory as a second argument (note: copy() vs. copyfile())

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'm writing my first python script, doesn't know much about the existing library.

Comment: spelling error, in line 'assert not os.path.isabs(scrfile)' the `scrfile` to `srcfile`

Answer (score 25):

take a look at [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html). `shutil.copyfile(src, dst)` will copy a file to another file.

Note that `shutil.copyfile` will not create directories that do not already exist.  for that, use [`os.makedirs`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.makedirs)