# running command via subprocess on Windows with spaces in filenames

Tags: python, windows, bash, subprocess

To run a command in python, for Windows, I do:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(lsCommand, shell=True)
```

where `lsCommand` is a list of strings that make up the bash command.  This works, except when it contains some input with spaces in it.  For example, copying + changing a name:

To try and do `cp "test 123" test123`:

```
lsCommand = ['cp', 'test 123', 'test123']
subprocess.check_output(lsCommand, shell=True)
```

fails because it thinks I am trying to do `cp "test" "123" test123`.  Error (doing google storage stuff):

```
python: can't open file 'c:\GSUtil\gsutil.py cp -n gs://folderl/test': [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Then I try

```
subprocess.check_output('cp "test 123" test123', shell=True)
```

Same shit.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using `shell=True`?  Given a list without `shell=True` should work I think.

Comment: @zondo not on windows, no.  Linux yay

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess

Comment: doing anything without `shell=True` fails for me.  Several questions I read stated that it is required in Windows.  For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531683/problems-using-subprocess-call-in-python-2-7-2-on-windows

Comment: You appear to be running cp.exe from some Unix-like environment (e.g. MSYS), so there's no need to run the command via cmd.exe, i.e. `shell=True` on Windows. Your life will be simpler without it. Also, never use an args list with `shell=True` on either Windows or Unix systems. (It's for different reasons on Windows vs. Unix, but the same advice applies.)

Comment: Roman: It was required there because `cmd` is an internal command.

Comment: What error do you get without using the cmd shell?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input.  Unfortunately I'll have to wait till tomorrow to reply to you @eryksun.  They shut the vpn down and the guy just went home.  I'll test as soon as I can and will post the results.

Comment: FYI, using `subprocess` at all here is kind of silly, when Python supports it directly, no external program nonsense, with [`shutil.copyfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile).

Answer (score 0):

`cp` is not an [internal command](http://ss64.com/nt/) and therefore you don't need `shell=True` ([though you might need to specify a full path to `cp.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24789749/4279)).

The internal interface for starting a new subprocess on Windows uses a string i.e., it is up to the specific application how to interpret a command-line. [The default MS C runtime rules (imlemented in `subprocess.list2cmdline()` that is called implicitly if you pass a list on Windows)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#converting-an-argument-sequence-to-a-string-on-windows) should work fine in this case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(['cp', 'test 123', 'test123'])
```

If you want to use `shell=True` then the program that interprets the command line is `cmd.exe` and you should use its escape rules ([e.g., `^` is a meta-character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27864103/4279)) and pass the command as a string as is (as you see it in the Windows console):

```
check_call('copy /Y /B "test 123" test123', shell=True)
```

Obviously, you don't need to start an external process, to [copy a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12842997/4279):

```
import shutil

shutil.copy('test 123', 'test123')
```

Answer (score 0):

for Ubuntu:

```
subprocess.check_output(['list', 'of', 'commands with spaces'])
```

for Windows:

```
subprocess.check_output('single command "string with spaces"')
```

Thanks for info that I don't need `shell=True`.