# unexpected results while copying file using shutil

Tags: python-3.x, shutil

I want to copy one file to another. From the accepted answer of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994488/copy-file-or-directory-in-python), I have done:

```
def fcopy(src):
    dst = os.path.splitext(src)[0] + "a.pot"
    try:
        shutil.copy(src, dst)
    except:
        print("Error in copying " + src)
        sys.exit(0)
```

and using it as:

```
print(atoms)
for q in range(0, len(atoms), 2):
    print(type(atoms[q]))
    print(atoms[q], fcopy(atoms[q]))
```

This is quite a few check down inside the code, but I expect that does not matter as long as it finds `atoms[q]`. But the result I am getting is:

```
['Mn1.pot', 'Mn2.pot']   <= result of print(atoms)
<class 'str'>            <= result of type(atoms)
Mn1.pot None             <= result of print(atoms,fcopy(atoms)). 
['Mn3.pot', 'Mn4.pot']
<class 'str'>
Mn3.pot None
['Mn5.pot', 'Mn6.pot']
<class 'str'>
Mn5.pot None
['Mn7.pot', 'Mn8.pot']
<class 'str'>
Mn7.pot None
```

Where I was expecting the `print(atoms[q], fcopy(atoms[q]))` to give me `Mn1.pot Mn1a.pot`

I am still a beginner in python, so it will be great if someone can show me what's going wrong here.

Comment: You're missing a return statement.

Comment: Thanks. 
adding `return dst` solves it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting an error -- if you did you would see the `Error in copying` message printed.

The part you need to know is that every Python function returns a value.  If you do not tell Python what value to return, Python returns `None`.

So if you want the destination file to be returned to the caller, you have to do it yourself:

```
def fcopy(src):
    dst = os.path.splitext(src)[0] + "a.pot"
    try:
        shutil.copy(src, dst)

        return dst   # this line should be added

    except:
        print("Error in copying " + src)
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: did that, as my comment. but thanks.

Comment: @BaRud: I added the answer for two reasons:  1) every question should have an answer; and 2) others might have the same question, and a comment doesn't explain much.