# Copy a Single File in a DIR & in its sub directories

Tags: python, copy

I am new at python & am trying to make a mass file coping python script, which should copy a single file in a DIR and in its subdir. I have found a script but it has an error:

```
import os, sys, time 
time.sleep(1) 
path = sys.argv[1] 
file = sys.argv[2] 
exe = "find %s -name "index.*" -exec cp %s {} ;" % (path, file) 
os.system(exe)
```

I have also tried this system command 'cp -r file /path/**'  with * i can determine how deeper I wanna copy my file into a dir this command works fine but I can't do it with python while having file & path as 2 variables.

Comment: First of all, you need to do something about those quotes inside the string on line 5...

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994488/copy-file-or-directories-recursively-in-python