# Recursively copy the *contents* of a directory

Tags: robotframework

Using any of the standard Robot libraries, is it possible to recursively copy the *contents* of a directory to an existing destination directory?

Basically, I'm looking for the equivalent of the following shell command: `cp -r foo/. bar` (note the trailing dot)

I tried `Copy Directory` but this creates a directory `foo` inside `bar` (as documented) and it doesn't stop doing that even when supplying the trailing dot. `Copy Files` chokes when it encounters a directory.

Is there anything I overlooked? Or do I need to just call `cp -r` myself?

Comment: If you make sure that `bar` as `destination` param in `Copy Directory    ./foo    bar/` doesn't exist, there will be no `foo` created inside `bar`. Perhaps that's one solution (not a very nice one).

Comment: @pavelsaman Unfortunately that is no option, as ``bar`` is some rather largish directory containing lots of files and subdirectories. I just need to copy over everything contained in ``foo``.

Comment: Grab some of the answers here that suites you the most, create a python file with the function and import it in your test; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994488/copy-file-or-directories-recursively-in-python/1994840. HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I only need this to work on Linux, I ended up implementing a custom keyword calling `cp -r`. If this is ever needed cross-platform, then I'll follow the suggestions to directly [implement it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994488/copy-file-or-directories-recursively-in-python/1994840).

```
Copy Directory Contents
   [Documentation]   Recursively copies the contents of the source directory into the destination.
   [Arguments]   ${source}   ${destination}
   Directory Should Exist   ${source}
   Directory Should Exist   ${destination}
   ${result} =   Run Process   cp   -r   ${source}/.   ${destination}/
   Should Be Equal As Integers   ${result.rc}   0
```