# python : How to copy full path of folders to other folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, copy

For example i want to **copy** `C:\Users\RonSolo\Documents\copy\sources\Books\Songs\pictures\Html\css`

**to**

`C:\Users\RonSolo\Documents\copy\destination`

**the result should be**

`C:\Users\RonSolo\Documents\copy\destination\C\Users\RonSolo\Documents\copy\sources\Books\Songs\pictures\Html\css`

I just learned python basics still trying to find a way, if you guys can help me with a solution it would be great. (for practice purposes)

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to concatenate two strings together?

Comment: ... or are you trying to copy a folder to another location?

Comment: I am trying to copy a folder to another location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), it makes handling paths easier. And since you're on Windows, paths contain backslashes as separator, which Python interprets as escape sequence - so you have to add the `r` directive ("raw string literal").

```
from pathlib import Path

src = Path(r'C:\Users\RonSolo\Documents\copy\sources\Books\Songs\pictures\Html\css')
dst = Path(r'C:\Users\RonSolo\Documents\copy\destination') / str(src).replace(':', '')

# dst
# WindowsPath('C:/Users/RonSolo/Documents/copy/destination/C/Users/RonSolo/Documents/copy/sources/Books/Songs/pictures/Html/css')
```

Now you can use `copytree` to copy all the content, see [Copy file or directories recursively in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1994488/10197418):

```
import shutil

shutil.copytree(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use shutil library. you need to replace your "source" and "destination" path to this code:

```
import shutil
# Source path 
src = ' C:\Users\RonSolo\Documents\copy\sources\Books\Songs\pictures\Html\css'
# Destination path  
dest = 'C:\Users\RonSolo\Documents\copy\destination'
destination = shutil.copytree(src, dest)
```

"copytree" use for copying directories. for files you can use

```
shutil.copy
```

Comment: C:\Users\RonSolo\projects\Udemy-python-repo\python-code\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/RonSolo/projects/Copy-with-Structure/Code/copy.py
  File "C:/Users/RonSolo/projects/Copy-with-Structure/Code/copy.py", line 21
    src = ' C:\Users\RonSolo\Documents\copy\sources\Books\Songs\pictures\Html\css'
          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 3-4: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as following:

```
p1 = 'C:\Users\RonSolo\Documents\copy\sources\Books\Songs\pictures\Html\css'
p2 = 'C:\Users\RonSolo\Documents\copy\destination'

ans = p2+'\'+p1
```